# obtain element of many to many laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I sorry for my bad English :-)  my problem is the next:

I have the next relations with many to many

Class Order

```
class Order extends Model
  {

  public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
  }

  public function products(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Product', 'order_product')
        ->withPivot('order_id', 'product_quantity', 'subtotal');
  }

  public function pay(){
    $this->hasOne('App\Pay');
  }

  public function status(){
    $this->hasOne('App\Statu');
  }
}
```

class Product

```
class Product extends Model
{
  public function images(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Image');

  }

  public function carts(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cart', 'cart_product')
        ->withPivot('cart_id','quantity');
  }

  public function orders(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_product')
        ->withPivot('product_id', 'product_quantity', 'subtotal');
  }
}
```

Class User

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
  protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'password', 'address', 'telephone', 'mobile', 'rif',    'ci',
 ];

 /**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
  protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
  ];

  public function cart(){
    return $this->hasOne('App\Cart');
  }

  public function orders(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Order');
  }
}
```

Class Pay

```
class Pay extends Model
{
  public function order(){
    $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
  }
}
```

Class Statu

```
class Statu extends Model
{
  protected $table = 'status';

  public function order(){
    $this->belongsTo('App\Order');
  }
}
```

the method in the controller is:

```
 public function index(){
    $orders = User::find(Auth::user()->id)->orders;

        return view('order.list', compact('orders'));
    }
```

the error is present at the view(**I want to show the name that represents the identifier of the table STATU**)

```
<tbody>
   @foreach($orders as $order)
     <tr>
        <th class="row">{{ $order->id }}</th>  
        <td>{{ $order->date }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->status_id }}</td><-- ***HERE***
        <td>{{ $order->pay_id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->total_product }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->mount }}</td>
        <td><a class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" href="detail/{{ $order->id }}">detalles</a></td>
        </tr>  
    @endforeach
 </tbody>
```

the error

Comment: @manniL You need to provide the error message and some context if you can.

Comment: thanks @manniL, no present error in the $order->status_id. but I want to have is the name that represents the id in the STATU table. I do not get it

Answer (score 0):

To further explain, you are accessing the statu_id in the orders object! but if you need the name you have to retrieve it the status related to that order first just like i did here

This should work

**controller**

```
     $orders = Order::where('user_id',Auth::user()->id)->get();
return view('order.detail', compact('orders'));
```

**View**

```
    <td>{{ $order->status()->name or 'NULL'}}</td>  //change ->name to whatever you have in db that u want to show
```

Comment: thanks for the comments, I will make the case for future questions. Previously I tried what you have given me but I gives the following error **Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: can you explain how you return  $items but you use $orders?

Comment: yea try to fix it and tell me did it work or no and i think you should use eagler loading(just like in my answer) to avoid too much querys

Comment: yes, excuse me. I was wrong. I  have refreshed the controller. Please you check

Comment: sorry but no, i have error **Trying to get property of non-object**

Comment: ErrorException in Model.php line 2691:
Relationship method must return an object of type Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation (View: /var/www/html/osc/resources/views/order/list.blade.php)

Comment: i added the () that should fix i think! if the same probleme remain tell me pls

Comment: i have the error **FatalErrorException in Builder.php line 638:
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null**

Comment: this would be my last try, try to comment all other things in the loop {{--  --}} keep only the status <td> , i edited my answer check it! last try

Comment: sorry but I receive only null

Comment: aare you sure that the order have a status? i mean data in db?

Comment: yes i sure. table status: columns (id) and (denomination_sta)  / table orders: contains (status_id) correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is absurd, but the error I've had in:

```
 public function pay(){
    $this->belongsTo('App\Pay');
}

public function status(){
    $this->belongsTo('App\Statuss');
}
```

**not to return**, i fix with:

```
 public function pay(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Pay');
}

public function status(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Statuss');
}
```

and now correctly in the view

```
<td>{{ $order->status->name }}</td>
<td>{{ $order->pay->name }}</td>
```